# File.Exists e a acentuação

Tags: c#, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos

Tenho um sistema desenvolvido em Webforms (eca!) que verifica a existência de uma imagem para então exibi-la.

Tudo está funcionando corretamente, porém, quando o caminho da imagem tem acentos, o método `File.Exists` parece estar retornando `false`.

O que posso fazer para contornar isso?

Exemplo:

```
 string img1 = Server.MapPath("\Fotos\Imagem.jpg");
 string img2 = Server.MapPath("\Fotos\Imagem-com-acentuação.jpg");

Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(img1)); // true
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(img2)); // false
```

Atualização: Escrevi e testei a existência de um arquivo com acentuação manualmente e deu certo. Eu começo a desconfiar que o problema seja na montagem do caminho do arquivo, que foi feito da seguinte forma:

```
string imgUrl = "~\\Fotos\\Fotos_" + Codigo + "\\" + e.Row.Cells[20].Text;
```

Comment: tenta usar o HtmlEncode: `string img2 = Server.MapPath(Server.HtmlEncode("\\Fotos\\Imagem-com-acentuação.jpg"));`

Comment: @RovannLinhalis pera aí, deixa eu testar aqui. Se o `Text` estiver mandando os valores codificados, o problema provavelmente é esse mesmo.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis OPA! Era isso mesmo, kkkkk. O caminho estava sendo escrito assim: `Fotos\Fotos_98\Ti&#227;oz&#227;o.jpg`. Vou alterar isso aqui, achei uma péssima ideia de quem fez pegar o valor direito do Html :\

Comment: Responde aí para a gente finalizar a pergunta :p

Comment: Bem, na verdade, não seria o contrário? Eu acho que eu deveria usar "decode"?

Comment: já já melhoro a resposta...ocupado aqui =] que bom que resolveu =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível que a string com o nome do arquivo esteja sendo codificado em HTML, você pode reverter isso usando `HtmlEncode` e `HtmlDecode`:

```
string arquivo = "Imagem-com-acentuação.jpg";

string codificada = Server.HtmlEncode(arquivo); //Imagem-com-acentua&ccedil;&atilde;o.jpg

string decodificada = Server.HtmlDecode(codificada); //Imagem-com-acentuação.jpg
```

Como você explicou nos comentários, o nome do arquivo já está sendo passado codificado, então seu código ficaria assim:

```
string img2 = Server.MapPath(Server.HtmlDecode(codificada));
```

Answer (score 0):

Vi um código aqui nunca classe que lista um diretório com um comentário para "tratar caminhos com acentos". Ao ver sua pergunta me lembrei disso e fui atrás.  Esse é o código (escrevi um path qualquer para exemplificar):

```
var path = @"c:\teste\senão\término\um path com textão.txt";
var pathD = path.Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormD);
```

Se observar o valor das duas variáveis, aparentemente é igual, a se testar com `path == pathD` retorna false.

Fui ler mais sobre o método `Normalize` e pelo que vi, ele muda algo na representação binária da string, mudando caracteres unicode. A visualização é a mesma, mas a comparação (inclusive no `File.Exists`) muda.

Aqui funciona bem com `File.Exists`. Para exemplificar fiz um fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8PcNcp

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas na verdade, como descrito nos comentários, o problema foi originado pelo fato do caminho da imagem estar sendo montado em cima de um valor extraido do HTML (que vem codificado).